# Firebase sign in not working, no change to code or firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Today i got on, and wanted to do some work, when I realised that my sign in nor registration was working on my app. There is an error "Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.", however I have not changed anything on firebase or in the code, and it has been working well ever since today.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing was changed, the most likely problem is that the emulator doesn't have connection to the internet. You can check one in browser.